# Generate PDF using Managed Bean with custom HTTP headers

Tags: jsf-2, http-headers, reporting, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

## Background

Generate a report in various formats (e.g., PDF, delimited, HTML) using an ADF Task Flow.

## Problem

HTTP headers are being sent twice: once by the framework and once by a bean.

### Source Code

The source code includes:

- Button Action
- Managed Bean
- Task Flow

#### Button Action

The button action:

```
<af:commandButton text="Report" id="submitReport" action="Execute" />
```

#### Managed Bean

The Managed Bean is fairly complex. The code to `responseComplete` is getting called, however it does not seem to be called sufficiently early to prevent the application framework from writing the HTTP headers.

*HTTP Response Header Override*

```
/**
 * Sets the HTTP headers required to indicate to the browser that the
 * report is to be downloaded (rather than displayed in the current
 * window).
 */
protected void setDownloadHeaders() {
  HttpServletResponse response = getServletResponse();
  response.setHeader( "Content-Description", getContentDescription() );
  response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename="
    + getFilename() );
  response.setHeader( "Content-Type", getContentType() );
  response.setHeader( "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
    getContentTransferEncoding() );
}
```

*Issue Response Complete*

```
getFacesContext().responseComplete();
```

*Bean Run and Configure*

```
public void run() {
  try {
    Report report = getReport();
    configure(report.getParameters());
    report.run();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private void configure(Parameters p) {
  p.put(ReportImpl.SYSTEM_REPORT_PROTOCOL, "http");
  p.put(ReportImpl.SYSTEM_REPORT_HOST, "localhost");
  p.put(ReportImpl.SYSTEM_REPORT_PORT, "7002");
  p.put(ReportImpl.SYSTEM_REPORT_PATH, "/reports/rwservlet");
  p.put(Parameters.PARAM_REPORT_FORMAT, "pdf");

  p.put("report_cmdkey", getReportName());
  p.put("report_ORACLE_1", getReportDestinationType());
  p.put("report_ORACLE_2", getReportDestinationFormat());
}
```

#### Task Flow

The Task Flow calls Execute, which refers to the bean's `run()` method:

```
entry -> main -> Execute -> ReportBeanRun
```

Where:

```
  <method-call id="ReportBeanRun">
    <description>Executes a report</description>
    <display-name>Execute Report</display-name>
    <method>#{reportBean.run}</method>
    <outcome>
      <fixed-outcome>success</fixed-outcome>
    </outcome>
  </method-call>
```

The bean is assigned to the `request` scope, with a few managed properties:

```
  <control-flow-rule id="__3">
    <from-activity-id>main</from-activity-id>
    <control-flow-case id="ExecuteReport">
      <from-outcome>Execute</from-outcome>
      <to-activity-id>ReportBeanRun</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
  </control-flow-rule>

  <managed-bean id="ReportBean">
    <description>Executes a report</description>
    <display-name>ReportBean</display-name>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    ...
  </managed-bean>
```

The `<fixed-outcome>success</fixed-outcome>` strikes me as incorrect -- I don't want the method call to return to another task.

## Restrictions

The report server receives requests from the web server exclusively. The report server URL cannot be used by browsers to download directly, for security reasons.

## Error Messages

The error message that is generated:

> Duplicate headers received from server
>
> Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION): Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.

Nevertheless, the report *is* being generated. Preventing the framework from writing the HTTP headers would resolve this issue.

## Question

How can you set the HTTP headers in ADF while using a Task Flow to generate a PDF by calling a managed bean?

## Ideas

Some additional ideas:

- Override the Page Lifecycle Phase Listener (`ADFPhaseListener` + `PageLifecycle`)
- Develop a custom Servlet on the web server

## Related Links

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/adf-bip-ucm-integration-179699.pdf
- http://www.slideshare.net/lucbors/reports-no-notes#btnNext
- http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2012/03/calling-oracle-report-from-adf-applications.html?goback=%2Egde_4212375_member_102062735
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29049_01/web.1112/e16182/adf_lifecycle.htm#CIABEJFB

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect implementation of RFC 2183:

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
  + getFilename() );
```

The `;` cannot be a `,`.